# How to add styling to selected ListTile in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have multiple List Tiles and I want to add a few styles to the one which is selected. To set the color of the selected tile, I have used `ListTileTheme` so whichever tile gets selected will get the color defined in `ListTileTheme`.

```dart
ListTileTheme(
  selectedTileColor: Colors.white,
  child: ...
),
```

I also want to set border radius on top left and bottom left of `ListTile`, for this purpose I am using `ClipRRect`

```dart
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
    topLeft: Radius.circular(32),
    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(32),
  ),
  child: ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.people),
    title: Text('Teams'),
    onTap: () {},
    selected: true,
  ),
),
```

This works well as can be seen in the image below:

[image]

but I had to manually add it to a particular list tile. Unlike selected tile color which was defined once and it got applied automatically on any tile where the selected property is true, how to set `ClipRRect` too in similar fashion so that whichever tile gets selected receives border radius on top left and bottom left?

Comment: do you use any builder for your listTiles? Or do you use it straight in `Column(children:ListTiles(), ListTiles())`?

Comment: @FarhanSyah No, I am not using builders. I have added List Tiles one by one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add styling to selected List Tile, I used `ListView.builder`, added all the menu items to display in list tile in a Map.

```dart
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _menuItem = [
    {
      "title": "Home",
      "icon": Icon(Icons.home),
      "selected": false,
    },
    {
      "title": "Teams",
      "icon": Icon(Icons.people),
      "selected": true,
    },
    {
      "title": "Ideas",
      "icon": Icon(Icons.lightbulb),
      "selected": false,
    }
];
```

and then using `ListView.builder` to loop through them.

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: _menuItem.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(32),
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(32),
      ),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: _menuItem[index]['icon'],
        title: Text(_menuItem[index]['title']),
        selected: _menuItem[index]['selected'],
        onTap: () {
          if (!_menuItem[index]['selected'])
            changeSelectedMenu(index);
          },
      ),
    );
 },
)
```

`changeSelectedMenu` function ensures that the clicked menu item gets the `selected` property set to true. As posted in question, selected tile color is set to true and whichever tile is white gets the rounded radius from `ClipRRect`.

Answer (score 14):

You have probably done the same mistake as i did and did not study all properties of ListTile. ListTile has several useful properties like `shape` or `selectedTileColor` that can solve your problems.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SideMenuItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
  final GestureTapCallback onTap;
  final bool active;

  const SideMenuItem({required this.title, required this.icon, required this.onTap, required this.active, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var borderRadius = const BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(32), bottomRight: Radius.circular(32));
    return ListTile(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: borderRadius),
      selectedTileColor: Colors.orange[100],
      selected: active,
      onTap: () {},
      leading: Icon(icon),
      title: Text(title),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code:

```
class MyListTile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
_MyListTileState createState() => _MyListTileState();
}
class _MyListTileState extends State<MyListTile> {
 int index ;
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.cyanAccent,
  body: ListView(
    children: [
      ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: index != null && index == 0?BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(32),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(32),
        ):BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(0),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0),
        ),
        child:Container(
          color: index != null && index == 0?Colors.white:null,
          child: ListTile(
            focusColor: Colors.white,
            leading: Icon(Icons.people),
            title: Text('Teams'),
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                index = 0;
              });
            },
            selected: index != null && index == 0?true:false,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: index != null && index == 1?BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(32),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(32),
          ):BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(0),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0),
          ),
          child:Container(
            color: index != null && index == 1?Colors.white:null,
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.people),
              title: Text('Teams'),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  index = 1;
                });
              },
              selected: index != null && index == 1,
            ),
          ),
      ),
      ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: index != null && index == 2?BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(32),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(32),
          ):BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(0),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0),
          ),
          child:Container(
            color: index != null && index == 2?Colors.white:null,
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.people),
              title: Text('Teams'),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  index = 2;
                });
              },
              selected: index != null && index == 2,
            ),
          ),
      ),
      ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: index != null && index == 3?BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(32),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(32),
          ):BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(0),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0),
          ),
          child:Container(
            color: index != null && index == 3?Colors.white:null,
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.people),
              title: Text('Teams'),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  index = 3;
                });
              },
                 selected: index != null && index == 3,
               ),
             ),
         ),
       ],
     ),
   );
 }
```

}

hope its help!
but that's not good solution .you should use builder